# ImportError: No module named allcontrols with pywinauto and py2exe

Tags: python, py2exe, pywinauto

I want to generate an `.exe` file from a python script which includes the `pywinauto` module.

It builds fine, however when running the resulting `dist\pywinauto_sample.exe`, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pywinauto_sample.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pywinauto import application
  File "pywinauto\application.pyc", line 68, in <module>
  File "pywinauto\controlactions.pyc", line 45, in <module>
  File "pywinauto\tests\__init__.pyc", line 128, in <module>
  File "pywinauto\tests\__init__.pyc", line 114, in __init_tests
ImportError: No module named allcontrols
```

Here's my `pywinauto_sample.py`:

```
import pywinauto
from pywinauto import application
app = pywinauto.application.Application()
```

And here's my `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['pywinauto_sample.py'])
```

I compile the program with:

```
python setup.py py2exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(
    console=
    [
        'pywinauto_sample.py'
    ],
    options=
    {
        "py2exe":
        {
            "includes":
            [
                "pywinauto.tests.truncation",
                "pywinauto.tests.translation",
                "pywinauto.tests.repeatedhotkey",
                "pywinauto.tests.overlapping",
                "pywinauto.tests.missingextrastring",
                "pywinauto.tests.missalignment",
                "pywinauto.tests.miscvalues",
                "pywinauto.tests.leadtrailspaces",
                "pywinauto.tests.comparetoreffont",
                "pywinauto.tests.comboboxdroppedheight",
                "pywinauto.tests.asianhotkey",
                "pywinauto.tests.allcontrols",
            ]
        }
    }
)
```

Source: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.py2exe/4663